# Ошибка при чтении xml c# входная строка имела неверный формат

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде просто код, но чуть что и сразу ошибка, то зависит от xml, то хотел добавить `<picture>` опять ошибка. Как сделать код менее требовательный к содержимому?

Прогнал я по F11. Вылетает на строке `newRow["id"] = int.Parse(elm.Attribute("id").Value);`

В файле с таким кодом вылетает: `<offer available="true" type="vendor.model" id="X15042088746">`

А с таким кодом работает (не вылетает): `<offer available="true" id="238258">`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ReadXml();
        }

        private DataTable CreateTable()
        {
            //создаём таблицу
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("offers");

            //создаём три колонки
            DataColumn colID = new DataColumn("Id", typeof(String));
            DataColumn colname = new DataColumn("name", typeof(String));
            DataColumn colcategoryId = new DataColumn("categoryId", typeof(String));
 //           DataColumn colpicture = new DataColumn("picture", typeof(String));

            //добавляем колонки в таблицу
            dt.Columns.Add(colID);
            dt.Columns.Add(colname);
            dt.Columns.Add(colcategoryId);
 //           dt.Columns.Add(colpicture);

            return dt;
        }

        private DataTable ReadXml()
        {
            DataTable dt = null;

            try
            {
                //загружаем xml файл
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"file.xml");

                //создаём таблицу
                dt = CreateTable();

                DataRow newRow = null;

                //получаем все узлы в xml файле
                foreach (XElement elm in xDoc.Descendants("offer"))
                {
                    //создаём новую запись
                    newRow = dt.NewRow();

                    //проверяем наличие атрибутов (если требуется)
                    if (elm.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        //проверяем наличие атрибута id
                        if (elm.Attribute("id") != null)
                        {
                            //получаем значение атрибута
                            newRow["id"] = int.Parse(elm.Attribute("id").Value);
                        }
                    }

                    //проверяем наличие xml элемента name
                    if (elm.Element("name") != null)
                    {
                        //получаем значения элемента name
                        newRow["name"] = elm.Element("name").Value;
                    }

                    if (elm.Element("categoryId") != null)
                    {
                        newRow["categoryId"] = int.Parse(elm.Element("categoryId").Value);
                    }

                    //if (elm.Element("picture") != null)
                    //{
                    //    newRow["picture"] = int.Parse(elm.Element("picture").Value);
                    //}

                    //добавляем новую запись в таблицу
                    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какая конкретно строка бросила исключение? И да, дайте сюда ваш файл.

Comment: Никакая строка. Появляется это сообщение.

Comment: А вы поставьте breakpoint в начале метода `ReadXml` и оттрассируйте.

Comment: @Андрей вместо `ex.Message` укажите `ex.ToString()` и получите стектрейс -- в нем видно, на какой строке была ошибка.

Comment: @Андрей а для чего из XDocument копировать данные в DataTable? у вас так получается две копии данных в памяти

Comment: Нашел код на просторах инета.

Comment: @Андрей - какое целое число Вы ожидаете получить из строки "X15042088746"?

Comment: @igor я не вижу целого числа я вижу String и подумал что строка

Comment: У вас `elm.Attribute("id").Value` есть строка `"X15042088746"`. Понятно, что `int.Parse(elm.Attribute("id").Value)` вылетит, в строке-то нет числа.

Comment: О, нет) как исправить чтобы проглатывало все что есть? Я и сейчас не вижу где в коде число принимается

Comment: уберите `int.Parse`, все равно ведь колонки в таблице Вы создаете строковые

Comment: А что должно быть в `newRow["id"]` в этом случае?

Comment: @Igor: И правда, колонки строковые :) Копипаст вреден.

Comment: Да, удалил `int.Parse` как предложил @Igor. Оставил `newRow["id"] = elm.Attribute("id").Value;` и все заработало! Чудеса. Спасибо всем за помощь ). Напишите как ответ...

Comment: Пожалуйста! Вы бы не копипастили всякую фигню из интернета :) Кстати, остальные `int.Parse` вам тоже не нужны.

Comment: @Igor: Думаю, вам стоит опубликовать ответ

Comment: @VladD пытаюсь так учиться, вот и копипаст. Да, про остальные int я уже понял по аналогии )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как все колонки в `DataTable` строковые, нет необходимости конвертировать значения атрибутов в числа:

```
newRow["id"] = elm.Attribute("id").Value;

...

newRow["categoryId"] = elm.Element("categoryId").Value;
```